# How can I make css transition last after unhovering?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I created a div that when hovering, reveals a form. the problem is each time im moving the cursor the transition takes place and filling the form become impossible. how can i make the transition work once and than stay/ last for long time?
*i found some information about the delay option but i didn't find a way to modify the delay time separately for the first hovering and then for when the cursor moves out of the div (when "unhovering")
. im looking for a pure css sulotion
HTML:

```
<form id="women">
          <label >
              <input type="text" name="fullName" >
          </label>
</form>
<div id="wcover"></div>
```

css:

```
#wcover{
    right: 177px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 291px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 337px;
    height: 402px;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: height 2s;
}   


#wcover: hover{
    height: 0px;
    background:black;
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything below?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your div is before the form, you may use a transition (e.g. of the `opacity` property) with a long delay on "*unhover*"

e.g.

Markup<sup>(*)</sup>

```
<div id="wcover">hover me</div>

<form id="women">
  <label >whats your name</label>
  <input type="text" name="fullName">
</form>
```

Css

```
form {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s 999999s;
}

div:hover + form {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0s;
}
```

After the `hover` event, thanks to the delay inserted, the user may takes up to 999.999 seconds (approx.ly 277.7 hours) to fill the form.

**Live Example**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPYOLB

---

<sup>(*)</sup>As a side note, for a matter of markup validation, you can't insert an heading into a label.

Answer (score 0):

You properly need some jQuery here....

`$("#wcover").hover(function() { 
    $("#wcover").addClass("hovered");
});`

And some CSS:
 `.hovered { //Properties here }`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could make use of a `checkbox` to show/hide your `div` on click. It is not very clear from your question as to whether you are showing the form which is shown in your code, or the `div` itself which contains another form.

Am assuming, that you have a form inside the `div`.

```css
#wcover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}
label[for=chk] { cursor: pointer; }
#chk { display: none; }
#chk:checked + #wcover { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<label>
    What's your name? 
    <input type="text" id="fullName" />
</label>
<br /><br />
<label for="chk">Click to Show/Hide Complete Form</label>
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
<div id="wcover">
    <form id="women">
    <h2>Complete Form</h2>
      <input type="text" /><br/>
      <input type="text" /><br/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not wrap it all in a containing div and apply the hover to that?

```
<div id="form-container">
    <form id="women">
        <label >
            <input type="text" name="fullName" >
        </label>
    </form>
    <div id="wcover"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use CSS transitionn delay property

```
#wcover{
    right: 177px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 291px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 337px;
    height: 402px;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: height 2s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}   
#wcover: hover{
    height: 0px;
    background:black;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

The above css will give delay after the mouse out. just reverce it to do it other way